# Better Padlock for outdoor bike shed

Tags: lock, storage

I have a padlock for my outdoor bike shed. In two years I've got through 2 of them.
It is of the type pictured.

[image: padlock]

They have both jammed in different ways, but ultimately I need something that survives all weathers better.

What can you recommend for a UK based user, Convenience is key. Especially, since the shed is opened and closed at least 4 times a day!

The shed can be found here: https://www.shedstore.co.uk/6x3-trimetals-metal-bike-shed-anthracite

And the locking setup is like so (the silver bar swings up for the shed to open)

[image: Trimetals Bike locking point]

### Final solution

Resorted to cutting a plastic bottle to cover the lock, and it works brilliantly, don't know why it took all the suggestions to do it!

[image: bottle used as lock cover]

Comment: Can you exclude that they jammed because someone poured/sprayed some chemical on them?

Comment: Yep, Unless someone has been sneaking around my back garden!

Comment: I suspect locks that 'look' like this are not uniform in quality and you've just been unlucky with the brand you have bought.  I live in a seaside town in Scotland (so ideal rusting conditions) and have a lock that looks like this bought from the local hardware store that has survived 8 years so far with only a couple of blasts of WD40 required in that time.

Comment: I don't have a specific product recommendation especially since it's not clear where in the world you are located, but there are any number of OUTDOOR/WEATHER RESISTANT padlocks on the market.  One type that I know stands up to weather well are the kinds that many self-storage facilities use.

Comment: What's the connection with bicycles?   Just that there are bikes in this shed?  This question may be on topic for DIY.SE, or great outdoors, or lifehacks.

Comment: Could you use a surface-mounted rim lock fastened to the inside of the door?

Comment: I've posted a picture of the lock mounting point to clarify

Comment: The issue perhaps may be related to the declaration of love written on the lock…so long as the relationship is solid, the lock will remain so too…

Comment: Check the Lock Picking Lawyer on YouTube for how much trust you'll be putting in locks in future times. Sobering!

Comment: It looks like a poor design for a lock holder. See edit to my answer.

Comment: Can you upgrade the door so the lock is embedded in the structure ?

Comment: After seeing a thief take an angle grinder to a locked bike that they could have just carried away with lock and all, and then the same thief breaking a heavier lock with angle grinder even when the bike was locked to a post that was screwed to floor and they could have just unscrewed it, and then not stealing the e-bike charger that was lying next to it, I wouldn't put too much trust in thieves either. For decent quality locks lockpicking seems to be more a hobby than practical way of breaking in.

Comment: My thinking is that if they are hard working enough to learn lock picking, the risk reward balance swings firmly on the side of: just earning money as a locksmith for people who have locked themselves out of their xyz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to take at least one of these three steps:

- buy a pricier padlock, with some warranty on its being weatherproof;
- make a little bit of cover from rain (i.e. a make-shift protecion from water dripping directly on the lock);
- every 6 months, spray it with wd40 (remove water, dust,crust, rust) and then proceed with lightly greasing (6 months intervals?) the moving parts. I'd put some light grease also with the key, but then you will have a greasy key, and it can be annoying (unless you have a small piece of cloth tucked under the rain cover above mentioned.

Regarding your comment, I found a tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpfpS-lJzDI) from someone having the same issue. According [to the author's comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpfpS-lJzDI&lc=Ugy1gNT7NugeMKkW9gt4AaABAg.99VNMMC0G5c99VNziNXIMo), written 4 years after uploading the video, it works.

EDIT:

after seeing the shed, it is clear that the lock has only casual deterrence value. The anchoring of the lock on the shed (the fixed "L" with the hole) would not stand a moderate force (for example a bike stand used as a leverage, pivoting on the arm of the shed itself).

Ignore my previous suggestions, Buy the cheapest combination bike lock that can go through the hole. The lighter, the crappier ---> the better: plastic and aluminium don't rust.

And don't forget to lock your bike(s) *inside* the shed, too.

Comment: I already did the 6 monthly greasing and crud removal but they still failed! What should I be searching for to buy a "cover" from the rain. Padlock shelter and padlock cover didn't really yield much!

Comment: nothing fancy
https://static2.bigstockphoto.com/8/7/3/large1500/378666184.jpg
or 
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/protecting-padlock-against-rain-plastic-600w-620094407.jpg

Comment: I don't have a workshop at my disposal, yet... , but the former of the "nothing fancy" looks pretty sufficient! I forgot to clarify that the shed is used several times a day, so the second image posted might be a bit annoying!
Following the images you posted I found this too: https://eoceanic.com/sailing/tips/15/259/extending_the_lives_and_serviceability_of_padlocks_on_a_boat/

Comment: @EdL It's definitely possible to purchase a more survivable lock, depending on your budget: https://masterlocks.com/collections/weather-tough

Comment: @EdL we have padlocks surviving on cave doors for years. They become covered with ice in winter (the caves breathe out warmer humid air), but they survive thanks to greasing. And they are quite ordinary ones, jist somewhat bigger than in your pictures. But it is true that they are on the inner side of the doors so no real rain on them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the shed security! I'm not worried about the shed since friends of mine in the same city have had the same shed in a front garden for 6 years now without any thefts, and only with cheap D-locks on theirs. It seems the one the thieves go for around us the wooden sheds.

Comment: Re: levering the shed open: Do you mean where the bolts used to attach the mount point to the shed body or how the arm is held down by the lock.

Comment: The bolts. Either the metal "L" can be detached easily (it seems flimsy) or I expect the bolts to be rusty and of poor quality.
My evaluation is a quick one -I would be happy to be proven wrong-.
Always keep in mind the weakest link. Wooden shed are broken in, even with the best available lock, because it is rather easy to detach the lock from the wooden structure.